# Ratio blocks issue

Tags: html, css

In one project I'm need to change block height in 16:9 and 9:16 ratio. Recently I'm used for this task solution in JS. But I'm prefer to use this pure CSS solution: [solution link](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html)

But I found a problem related to this. Please check JSFiddle find the details [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s58rr341/3/)

For 16:9 ratio I use a 56.25% padding-top value for 9:16 I use 117.77% value. But in a different screen size my blocks takes a different height. Is there any solution to fix this bug in a pure CSS?

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="magazine-item">
        <div class="item-image ratio ratio-horizontal">
          <div class="ratio-container">
            <div class="item-image-inner">
              <div class="item-label">
                Label
              </div>
              <div class="item-tag">
                1 <span class="icon-d-tag"></span>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="holder" style="background: url('//image.ibb.co/dnNXj5/horizontal.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
          <a href="">Title</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div class="magazine-item">
        <div class="item-image ratio ratio-vertical">
          <div class="ratio-container">
            <div class="item-image-inner">
              <div class="item-label">
                Label
              </div>
              <div class="item-tag">
                1 <span class="icon-d-tag"></span>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="holder" style="background: url('//i.imgur.com/XcPBLOU.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
          <a href="">Title</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div class="magazine-item">
        <div class="item-image ratio ratio-vertical">
          <div class="ratio-container">
            <div class="item-image-inner">
              <div class="item-label">
                Label
              </div>
              <div class="item-tag">
                1 <span class="icon-d-tag"></span>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="holder" style="background: url('//i.imgur.com/XcPBLOU.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
          <a href="">Title</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div class="magazine-item">
        <div class="item-image ratio ratio-vertical">
          <div class="ratio-container">
            <div class="item-image-inner">
              <div class="item-label">
                Label
              </div>
              <div class="item-tag">
                1 <span class="icon-d-tag"></span>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="holder" style="background: url('//i.imgur.com/XcPBLOU.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
          <a href="">Title</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div class="magazine-item">
        <div class="item-image ratio ratio-vertical">
          <div class="ratio-container">
            <div class="item-image-inner">
              <div class="item-label">
                Label
              </div>
              <div class="item-tag">
                1 <span class="icon-d-tag"></span>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="holder" style="background: url('//i.imgur.com/XcPBLOU.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
          <a href="">Title</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="magazine-item">
        <div class="item-image ratio ratio-horizontal">
          <div class="ratio-container">
            <div class="item-image-inner">
              <div class="item-label">
                Label
              </div>
              <div class="item-tag">
                1 <span class="icon-d-tag"></span>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="holder" style="background: url('//i.imgur.com/XcPBLOU.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
          <a href="">Title</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.ratio {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}

.ratio:after {
    display: block;
    content: ''
}

.ratio.ratio-vertical:after {
    padding-top: 117.77%
}

.ratio.ratio-horizontal:after {
    padding-top: 56.25%
}

.ratio .ratio-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where exactly in your fiddle are you applying the padding-top to achieve this? Please also include relevant CSS directly in your question. And what do you even mean, the height changes with different screen sizes? Well since it is based on the width, that is to be expected, no?

Comment: Sorry. Please check fiddle css section. There you will see all required css styles. Let me be more specific. I put blocks in a columns with a different width (col-6 + col-3 + col-3). And I need to have the same height for all blocks. I know that blocks are responsive :). But I expect that all blocks will resize with a different ratio. Please let me know if my explanation was unclear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the blocks *should* have different heights in different screen size because of the difference in screen width. If you want to fix a height, then you need to set a `max-width`.

Comment: Well your item in the col-6 element is not exactly twice the width of the ones in the col-3 elements to begin with, so ...